# Lumen: update records via json body

Tags: laravel, lumen

I have a Laravel Lumen API. I'm seeing an issue with the update functionality.

In my controller, the code for updating an item is:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {

        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
            'completed' => 'required',
         ]);

        $todo = Todo::find($id);
        $todo->name = $request->name;
        $todo->description = $request->description;
        $todo->completed = $request->completed;
        $todo->save();
        return response()->json(['status' => 'success']);
    }
```

I can update the todo item using:

```
http://lumen-todo.app/api/51?name=test&description=test&completed=1
```

however was hoping I could send the parameters in a json body, like this

```
PUT http://lumen-todo.app/api
{
  "id": 1
  "name": "Test",
  "description": "Test",
  "completed": 1,
}
```

For adding items, it works via a json body, so don't understand why it does not work for updates. For info, the 'add item' controller code is here:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'completed' => 'required'
     ]);

    $todo = new Todo();
    $todo->name = $request->name;
    $todo->description = $request->description;
    $todo->completed = $request->completed;
    $todo->save();
    return response()->json(['status' => 'success']);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the json data from request payload, validate and store it, use

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->json()->all();

    $this->validate($data, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'completed' => 'required'
     ]);

    $resource = $this->model->find($id);

    $resource->fill($request);
    $resource->save();

    return response()->json(['status' => 'success']);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this:

```
$todo = new Todo();
$todo->name = $request->name;
$todo->description = $request->description;
$todo->completed = $request->completed;
$todo->save();
```

Do, this:

```
use App\Todo;

protected $model;

public function __construct(Todo $model) {
    $this->model = $model;
}

$resource = $this->model->find($id);
$resource->fill($request);
$resource->save();
```

Also, you can do `json_decode()` function to change your json params to array and use that to validate and save data.